# Rails - Customize model validation error messages but without a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model that validates a form but it does not inherit from ActiveRecord....it does not have a database

I am validating certain fields in the model but i want to have custom validation messages.....in the past I've went into the

```
en.yml 

 en:
   activerecord:
     models: 
       mymodel: "CHANGE TO SOMETHING ELSE"
```

and could easily change it to whatever i want but it is not working for this model....i think its because its not inheriting from ActiveRecord.....

how can i customize my validation errors?

Answer (score 3):

try including translations like this:

include ActiveModel::Translation

EDIT:

if your model had an email attribute and the blank validation didnt pass you can format you locale like this

locale:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    attributes:
      mymodel:
        email: "foo"
    errors:
      models:
        mymodel:
          blank: "bar"
```

here are other errors you can add a locale
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml

Comment: after adding this to my model.....how do i write the en.yml file?  Do i use activemodel: instead of activerecord: ?

Comment: edited, hope it helps, dont forget to thumbs up and mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ActiveModel support for validations, as added in Rails 3.

```
class MyModel
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :name

  validates :name, presence: true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

end
```

Please see these references:

- http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/
- http://www.rubyinside.com/rails-3-0s-activemodel-how-to-give-ruby-classes-some-activerecord-magic-2937.html

The first link even includes use of an i18n file for errors, as you referenced.

Comment: i have included activemodel validations in my model

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you had validations working but not the translation of the error messages. The answer above to include ActiveModel::Translation will do the trick.